# Testing application with NightmareJS on Internet Explorer & Firefox

Tags: javascript, electron, nightmare

I want to test a website on Firefox and Internet Explorer using NightmareJS. Is there any way that we can make nightmare work to test the app on Firefox or IE? Or is there a way by which we can emulate electron browser with Firefox or IE so that nightmare in turn can test on emulated browsers?